# Change the horizontal scrollbar in ui-grid to be on left?

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-grid, ui-grid

Is there a way I can change the horizontal scroll-bar in `ui-grid` to be on the left instead of the right? I have scoured the web, and can't find a solution to this.

Comment: The convention is for the scroll bar to be on the right. Users will not expect it on the left (except maybe for RTL?). That's probably why you can't find it

Comment: I know. It is ONE client being difficult.... thanks for the confirmation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this kind of change mostly need some css changes.
simply find related class with inspect element and use this css on it.

direction:rtl change scrollbar to left and text-align bring your text to left.

```css
/* Styles go here */

.scroll{
  height:200px;
  overflow:scroll;
  direction:rtl;
  text-align: left;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <div class="scroll">
      <h1>Hello World</h1>
      <h1>Hello World</h1>
      <h1>Hello World</h1>
      <h1>Hello World</h1>
      <h1>Hello World</h1>
      <h1>Hello World</h1>
      <h1>Hello World</h1>
      <h1>Hello World</h1>

    </div>
  </body>

</html>
```